# SOCKET.IO Transport Polling 404 Error when starting

Tags: websocket, socket.io

I'm using the latest 4.1.3 socket.io server and client code.

My chat is at "https://example.com/folder"

I'm getting the following error:
"https://example.com/folder/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=NgcY9e8" 404 error when trying to initialize."

MY SERVER:

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const http = require('http');
const server = http.createServer(app);
const { Server } = require("socket.io");
const io = new Server(server);

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index.html');
});

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected');
    socket.on('chat message', (msg) => {
        console.log('message: ' + msg);
    });
});
server.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('-------------------- Started Server (Port 3000) --------------------');
});
```

MY CLIENT:

```
<script src="https://cdn.socket.io/4.1.3/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
var socket = io({
path: "/chat/socket.io/"
});
</script>
```

I'm not sure what the problem is.. is it something server side?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it.

Add the following block to your conf.d file for the site:

```
location ~ ^/(node|socket.io) {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header Host $host;
      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/;
      proxy_http_version 1.1;
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
      sub_filter /node /;
```